# How can the Tensorflow2 data pipeline be optimized?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I work with a large image dataset which I transform to tfrecords in the first step and load to a tf.data.dataset in the next.

But the dataset is so big that I can't get a bigger batch size than 10, despite the 12 GB GPU. Now the question arises, how I can optimize the loading of the images so that I can reach a bigger batch_size.

Is there a way to use maybe .fit_generator() to optimize this process?

Here is my current loading process of the training data (the validation data is transformed in the same way and is therefore not shown here as well):

```py
train_dataset = dataset.load_tfrecord_dataset(dataset_path, class_names_path, image_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (
        dataset.transform_images(x, image_size),
        dataset.transform_targets(y, anchors, anchor_masks, image_size)))
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
```

Start of my Trainingsphase:

```py
history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                            epochs=epochs,
                            callbacks=callbacks,
                            validation_data=val_dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are some constraints that depend on the hardware architecture, regardless of how much we may optimize from a software perspective.

In your case, the only way in which the batch size could be increased would be to lower the dimension of the images; otherwise you will not be able to increase the batch size.

```
tf.data.Dataset()
```

is an excellent library for manipulating data, and using the correct/necessary preprocessing steps like `prefetch` can indeed make you processing faster.

Nevertheless, due to the hardware constraints you cannot increase the batch size. Either decrease the image sizes in order to be able to increase the batch size or you need to opt for a bigger GPU >=16 GB VRAM.

Comment: So there is at the moment no other solution to load just large junks (maybe 8 GB) and train the model with these Data and after that reload the other junks of data?

In other words: There is at the moment no other software solution?

Comment: Yes, no other software solutions. In the end, regardless of the CPU/GPU communication optimization, loading a certain image into the memory takes a certain space.

Comment: That is why we use batches in the end...since we cannot load the entire dataset (full gradient descent) to train the networks; Of course, depending on the hardware architecture and dataset etc. this hyperparameter can vary and reach an upper threshold as you have noticed on your own.